# Ensure fsync did its job

Tags: c++, c, linux, filesystems

manpage for `fsync` says:

> If the underlying hard disk has write caching enabled, then the data
>   may not really be on permanent storage when fsync() / fdatasync()
>   return.

Is there any way how to ensure that data was physically written to the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not.

With `fsync` you tell your OS to write it to disk and as far as the OS is concerned, it has been written to disk.

If disks are faking this then it is not something you can really change unfortunately.
With proper disk systems (i.e. BBU raid setups) you can simply enable/disable write cache to avoid this mostly.

Do note that if you specify the `O_DIRECT` and `O_SYNC` flags, it *should* write it to disk: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: The "smart" disks I've seen, which did caching, also had a battery back-up to ensure that anything that was written to their cache did eventually end up on disk.  They more or less guaranteed that, except for write times, the behavior was exactly as if it were written to disk.

Comment: @JamesKanze: unfortunately I have seen a few cases where modern disks (especially SSD's) lie about what they've written. Luckily most disks to listen to the standards, but some don't :(

Comment: And that's before you even get to network file systems - then it's vendor/implementation specific (and of course also reliant on the underlying hardware, as already mentioned).