# Atomic file modification

Tags: java, windows, unix

There is region in file(possible small) that I want to overwrite.
Assume I calling fseek, fwrite, fsync. Is there any way to ensure atomicity of such region-rewriting operation, e.g. i need to be sure, that in any case of failure the region will contains only old(before modification) data, or only new(modified) data, but not a mix of this.

There are two thing i want to highlight.

**First**: It's ok if there is no way to atomically write ANY size region - we can handle it by appending data to the file, fsync'ing, and then rewriting 'pointer' area in file, then fsyncing again. However, if 'pointer' writing is not atomic, we still can have corrupted file with illegal pointers.

**Second**: I am pretty sure, writing 1-byte regions is atomic: i will not see in file any bytes I never put there. So we can use some tricks with allocating two regions for addresses and use 1-byte switch, so rewriting of region became - append new data, syncing, rewrite one of two(unused) pointer slots, syncing again, and then rewrite 'switch byte' and again syncing. So the overwrite region operation now contains at least 3 fsync invocation.

All of this would be much easer, if I will have atomic writing for longs, but do i really have it?

Is there any way to handle this situation without using method, mentioned in point 2?

Another question is - is there any ordering guarantee between writing and syncing?
For example, if i call fseek, fwrite [1], fseek, fwrite [2], fsync, can i have writing at [2] commited, and writing at [1] - not commited?

This question is applicable to linux and windows operation system, any particular answer(e.g. in ubuntu version a.b.c ....) is also wanted.

Comment: [fsync](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fsync) seems to be pretty implementation / filesystem dependent. http://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2009/03/16/ext4-vs-fsync-my-take/

Comment: What you're talking about is known as "commitment control", or "commit/rollback", or "transactions".

Comment: (The only (almost) fully reliable way to do what you want, absent some transaction processing facility on the box, is to do the old file swap -- copy old file to new, change new, rename new to replace old.)

Comment: @Hot Licks - the only reason i can't use file swap is because entire file can be large -> for any change I have to duplicate it, which have performance impact.

Comment: On some versions of Unix I think maybe it can be accomplished using a "copy on write" strategy that short-circuits the copy.  But probably not on Linux or Windoze.

Comment: @HotLicks: well, it should work that way using btrfs. OTOH, the only reliable way to do what the OP asks portably is to use a database, the database developers will have spent quite some time dealing with the subtleties of different systems.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually safe to assume that writing a 512 bytes chunks are done in one write by the HDDs.
However, i would not assume that. Instead, i'd go with your second solution, while adding a checksum to your write and verifying it before changing the pointer in the file.

Generally, it's a good practice to add checksum to everything written to disk.

To answer about "sync" guarantee - you can assume that. While sync is FS and disk dependent, let's say we are talking about 'reasonable' implementation.

- After the 1st `sync` the data is guaranteed to be flushed to the disk (the disk might have it 
  in it's cache still) and if the data you are expected to get whatever you wrote.
- If after the second `sync` the data of both syncs is in the disk cache, the situation you described can happen, but *IMHO* the probability of that is very low.

Anyway, there's no other mechanism which will promise you data is on disk. That's why you **must have checksums**.

Some more info: [Ensure fsync did its job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11612165/ensure-fsync-did-its-job)

Comment: Thanks for reply. About 'sync' guarantee, can you provide me "proof" for this assumption? Or, is it come from some(what?) source code tracking/expert(which?) advise?

Comment: augmented the answer with some info.